# Calculating CLR coded index size

Tags: clr

Im trying to read `MemberRef` coded index (`MemberRefParent`), Before I do that I need to know its size, according to *ECMA-335 Section II.24.2.6*, if I understood it correctly the coded index is calculated like so:

**my pseudo code**

```
m=max_rows(t0..tn-1); //returns the number of rows of the table that has the most rows.
if(m<2^(16-log(n)){
  //size is 2
} else {
  //size is 4
}
```

When I tested the code on CLI file, I got an error, I must have missed something, I hope someone can help me find where I was wrong.

**From section II.24.2.6, [ECMA-335](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-335.pdf)**

> If  e is a coded index that points into table ti out of n possible
>   tables t0, …tn-1, then it is stored as e << (log n) | tag{ t0, …tn-1}[
>   ti] using 2 bytes if the maximum number of rows of tables t0, …tn-1,
>   is less than 2^(16 – (log n)), and using 4 bytes otherwise.

-

> MemberRefParent: 3 bits to encode tag Tag
>
> TypeDef 0
>
> TypeRef 1
>
> ModuleRef 2
>
> MethodDef 3
>
> TypeSpec 4